# Construct React Component from a React Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a "higher-order" function in React that performs some permissions-based checks on the wrapped component and returns it accordingly.

**MyComponent.js**

```
...

export default Permissions(MyComponent)
```

**Permissions.js**

```
export default function Permissions(Component) {

  class NewComponent extends React.Component {

     // ... perform checks here

    render() {

      return {validPermissions && <Component />}

    }
  }
}
```

However, I'd like to be able to use this `Permissions` as a React Component (as opposed to a function that wraps the component export).

It would looks similar to this:

```
<Permissions>
    <MyComponent />
</Permissions>
```

When I run `React.Component.isPrototypeOf(Component.children)` I get false in these instances. My inclination is to think that the solution is to use some `React` or `ReactDOM` method to transform the [React Element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-elements) into a React *Component*, and then perform the same checks.

*How can I transform a React Element into a React Component?*

---

Update:

I gave the bit about permissions as context, but not looking for help with regard to implementing permissions.

I *am* basically looking for the opposite of `React.createElement(MyComponent)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a functional component, which combines the best of both worlds: it's simple (just a function!) and at the same time it's a proper stateless React component.

```
const Permissions = ({ granted, children }) =>
    granted ? React.Children.only(children) : null;
```

Usage:

```
<Permissions granted={true}>
    <MyComponent />
</Permissions>
```

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't allow me to transform the React Element to a React Component class...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this part of the question. Would you be able to show some example code, what do you need the "transformed" component for? What is the use case?